# Detect when UIMyView is closed

Tags: ios

I'm wondering if I do it in right way. I have my class UIMyView which I add to my main UIView. In that UIMyView i do some stuff using NSTimer and after all i call removeFromSuperView method to back to main UIView. I would like to notice when my UIMyView was closed. I use NSNotificationCenter to do it but maybe there is some other better way to do that ?

EDIT:
OK but I think you you didn't understand me. Using setHidden or containsObject we need to do this action for example puttin it to click Button or something like that. What i wanna do is checking when UIMyView is closed without any user interactions.

Comment: You take action when you close or remove you view, you need to write code of your any stuff/action where you wrote `removeFromSuperView` code..

Answer (score 1):

try this one .may be this will helpfull for you

```
BOOL hasMapView = [self.contentView.subviews containsObject:self.mapView];
UIView *fromView, *toView;
if (hasMapView)
{
    [btnMode setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"map-mode.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    fromView = self.mapView;
    toView = self.tblVideo;
    [self.tblVideo reloadData];
}
else
{
    fromView = self.tblVideo;
    toView = self.mapView;

    [btnMode setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"list-mode.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self reloadPins];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this instead of using removeFromSuperView

[urViewnm setHidden:YES];

Answer (score 0):

**To detect is View is closed**

```
BOOL isViewActive = [self.view.subviews containsObject:UIMyView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Using protocol you can achieve :

1.Create Protocol in  CustomViewController.h

```
 @protocol CustomViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void) didCustomViewControllerRemove:(id)sender;

@end

@interface CustomViewController : UIViewController

@property (retain) id <NSObject, CustomViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

1. Implement Protocol in CustomViewController.m

> ```
>   #import "CustomViewController.h"
>
>     @implementation CustomViewController
>
>   - (IBAction)cancelBtnPressed:(id)sender {    
>     [_delegate didCustomViewControllerRemove:self];
>
>   }
> ```

1. UIMyView.h

> #import "CustomViewController.h"
>
> @interface UIMyView : UIViewController '<'CustomViewControllerDelegate'>'
>
> {  }

1. use delegate method UIMyView.m

> ```
>  - (void) addCustomViewControllerMethod {
>
>   CustomViewController *obj = [CustomViewController alloc]
>  initWithNibName:@"CustomViewController" bundle:nil];
>
>   [self.view addSubView: obj];
>
>   obj.delegate =self; 
>
>  }      
>   - (void)didCustomViewControllerRemove:(id)sender {
>
>          [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];      
>  }
> ```